Add Steam launch menu to external game
...With SteamEdit you can edit Steam games launch menu, e.g.:

Is there a way to create a custom launch menu also for non-Steam external games?

What happens when you use SteamEdit on a (non-Steam) game that you added to Steam manually?

Can't be used ATM for external games: they are simply not listed, hence you can't edit them.
